# Adding Style to a div

Tags: html, css

I have a div I'm using to show it using the colorbox plugin.
It works fine!

But I want to show this div in my html, but having the same style. (I don't want the colorbox effect that the windows goes white. Just the effect of the style to the lightbox)

Something like this

[image]

I know this is something with CSS, but I'm not quite sure how to apply it.

Thanks for your help

```
<div id='inline_content' style='padding:10px; background:#fff;'>
    <p><strong>This content comes from a hidden element on this page.</strong></p>
    <p>The inline option preserves bound JavaScript events and changes, and it puts the content back where it came from when it is closed.</p>
    <p><a id="click" href="#" style='padding:5px; background:#ccc;'>Click me, it will be preserved!</a></p>

    <p><strong>If you try to open a new Colorbox while it is already open, it will update itself with the new content.</strong></p>
    <p>Updating Content Example:<br />
    <a class="ajax" href="../content/ajax.html">Click here to load new content</a></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needs style editing. Try adding a `border-bottom:` and font/color tweaks. 
 I believe this is what you want:

```
<div id='inline_content' style='
        padding:10px; 
        background:#fff; 
        border-style:solid; 
        width:620px;
'><p><strong>This content comes from a hidden element on this page.</strong></p>
    <p>The inline option preserves bound JavaScript events and changes, and it puts the content back where it came from when it is closed.</p>
    <p><a id="click" href="#" style='
        padding:5px; background:#ccc;
        color:#2E9AFE; font-family:"ARIAL";
        text-decoration:none; border-bottom-style:solid;
        border-width:1px; font-size:15px;
    '>Click me, it will be preserved!</a></p><p><strong>If you try to open a new Colorbox while it is already open, it will update itself with the new content.</strong></p>
    <p>Updating Content Example:<br />
    <a class="ajax" href="../content/ajax.html" style='
        color:#2E9AFE;
        font-family:"ARIAL";
'>Click here to load new content</a></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to add required width and border size, color and style ... something like "border-style:2px #000000 solid; width:700px;"

```
<div id='inline_content' style='padding:10px; background:#fff; border-style:2px #000000 solid; width:700px;'>
    <p><strong>This content comes from a hidden element on this page.</strong></p>
    <p>The inline option preserves bound JavaScript events and changes, and it puts the content back where it came from when it is closed.</p>
    <p><a id="click" href="#" style='padding:5px; background:#ccc;'>Click me, it will be preserved!</a></p>

    <p><strong>If you try to open a new Colorbox while it is already open, it will update itself with the new content.</strong></p>
    <p>Updating Content Example:<br />
    <a class="ajax" href="../content/ajax.html">Click here to load new content</a></p>
</div>
```